# Bitwise operation && overflow

Tags: java, overflow, bitwise-operators

Why the results of this two lines are different in java?

```
int a = 1;
System.out.println(a << 32); //output: 1
System.out.println(a << 31 << 1); //output: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [JLS 8 § 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then only the
>   five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used

When shifting an `int` the shift distance is thus effectively the value of the right operand mod 32 (at least when the right operand is non-negative).  So `a << 32` is basically the same as `a << 0`, i.e., just `a`.  But `a << 31 << 1` first shifts `a`, whose value is `0x00000001`, left by 31 to yield `0x80000000`, which is then shifted left by 1 to yield `0x00000000`.